# include json value in embed tag

Tags: embed

I am unable to set json value to scr attribute of embed tag from javascript file.

$.getJSON("url",function(data){

```
 jsonMovies = data.Movies;
 $.each(data.Movies, function(index,value){
     numofMovs[i]= index;
     if (numofMovs[i] == 'Movie6')
     {
        var parent = $('embed#video1').parent();            
        $('embed#video1').remove();             
        parent.append('<embed type="video/mp4" width="200px" height="200px" id = "video1"           
        src=value.Video />');   
     }
}
```

}
Please let me know the correct syntax for including the json value in src attribute (src=value.Video).

Thanks,
Surabhi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to concatenate the value into the string:

```
parent.append('<embed type="video/mp4"
      width="200px"
      height="200px"
      id="video1"
      src=' + value.Video + '/>');
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

There's a considerable difference between:

```
x = 'hello';
alert(x);   // shows hello
alert('x'); // shows x
```

Comment: I tried to concatenate the value but still the video is not playing.                                                 parent.append('<embed type="video/mp4" width="200px" height="200px" id = "video1" src=' + value.Video + '/>');

Comment: have you checked that `value.Video` actually contains a valid URL?

Comment: yes it contains the URL. I confirmed it with an alert statement.

Comment: Thanks Marc. After installing the QuickTime plug-in above code worked fine